# Можно ли помочь предложению, утонувшему в тире и запятых?

Tags: пунктуация

> И остановились мы на том самом моменте, когда в 1066 году Вильгельм
>   Завоеватель высадился со своей дружиной на берегах Альбиона  – в год
>   нормандского вторжения в Англию, в год, когда крестоносцы под
>   предводительством Готфрида Бульонского берут Иерусалим, в год, когда
>   Папа Римский Пасхалий II брошен в тюрьму Генрихом V – последним
>   королём из Салической (Франконской) династии, который требовал
>   короновать его императором, в тот самый год из удалённой обители в
>   горах над Римом, по происхождению князь, по сознательному выбору –
>   монах, потом аббат, потом и Папа Римский, приглашает в свой монастырь
>   нескольких мастеров из Константинополя (ныне Стамбул), дабы украсили
>   они его обитель.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замечания:

1) Предложение **по своей структуре  уже разделено на две части**,

2) можно использовать **точки с запятой**,

3) **кто** приглашает?

**И остановились мы на том самом моменте, когда в 1066 году Вильгельм Завоеватель высадился со своей дружиной на берегах Альбиона** – в год нормандского вторжения в Англию;

в год, когда крестоносцы под предводительством Готфрида Бульонского берут Иерусалим;

в год, когда Папа Римский Пасхалий II брошен в тюрьму Генрихом V – последним королём из Салической (Франконской) династии, который требовал короновать его императором.

**И в этот самый год из удалённой обители в горах над Римом (НЕКТО), по происхождению князь, по сознательному выбору – монах, потом аббат, потом и Папа Римский, приглашает в свой монастырь нескольких мастеров из Константинополя (ныне Стамбул), дабы украсили они его обитель.**

Comment: Приглашает тот, кто *по происхождению князь, по сознательному выбору – монах, потом аббат, потом и Папа Римский.* Некту я уже предложила автору. Видимо, иначе никак...

Comment: Подлежащего нет, все приложения  обособленные.

Comment: Мы его создали: НЕКТО!

Comment: Может быть, автор  придумает что-нибудь подходящее.

Comment: Меня смущают разные времена глагола: высадился, берут, брошен,  приглашает. Неужели такое допустимо?

Comment: Мне разброс глагольных форм кажется нормальным, могу только объяснить почему. Мы смотрим на события сверху и даже можем перемещаться по временной оси  года, оценивать значимость событий и их следствия. Вильгельм высадился - это отсчет для начала нового исторического периода; берут Иерусалим - это также  растянутое по времени событие с важным итогом (Первый крестовый поход увенчался успехом, в результате чего на Востоке образовались несколько государств крестоносцев). И наконец, оценив обстановку,  мы обращаемся с интересующему нас событию, которое видим в настоящем времени  - приглашает.